SpringBoot WebTestClient stuck on infinite stream
I've implemented an SSE controller to send events to the client when needed. It stays open indefinetely (meaning I don't ever call ResponseBodyEmitter#complete). It works fine, but I want/need to create tests for the controller.
Problem is that the test gets stuck on WebTestClient.RequestHeadersSpec#exchange because the stream is infinite. I could verify that by simply invoking ResponseBodyEmitter#complete after the first sent message.
I suspect this has something to do with the use of MVC instead of Webflux as the underlying implementation on my application. Nevertheless the documentation afirms it's ok to use WebTestClient to test an MVC application. So this should be possible without problems, right?
Here's the simplified version of the controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/events")
public class EventsController {

    @GetMapping(produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter subscribeToEvents() {
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);
        try {
            sseEmitter.send("Welcome!");

            // sseEmitter.complete(); // if this line is uncommented, test works
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return sseEmitter;
    }
}

and here's the test class:
@WebMvcTest(EventsController.class)
class EventsControllerTest {

    @Test
    void test(@Autowired WebTestClient webClient) {

        Flux<String> eventFlux = webClient.get().uri("/events")
                .accept(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .returnResult(String.class)
                .getResponseBody();

        StepVerifier.create(eventFlux)
                .expectNextMatches(e -> e.equals("Welcome!"))
                .thenCancel()
                .verify();
    }
}

Version is Spring Boot 3.2.4 and I followed the documentation described here

Something like this should work:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class SseApplicationTests {

    WebTestClient webClient= 
         WebTestClient.bindToServer()
                      .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                      .build();

    @Test
    void test() {

        Flux<String> eventFlux = webClient.get().uri("/events")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .returnResult(String.class)
                .getResponseBody();

        StepVerifier.create(eventFlux)
                .expectNextMatches(e -> e.equals("Welcome!"))
                .thenCancel()
                .verify();
    }

}



ok, but I'm slicing my test class so I don't  need to load the entire context which is really big. So would you care to elaborate on the solution? I mean, why should this work?
